# I am gettig FATAL EXCEPTION, from com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)

Tags: android

This is an error , which I get
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac;

======================================================================

### In My code

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
```

Comment: provide some code here

Comment: provide your `build.gradle` file for dependency check. And make sure to use same `supportLib` version of play services

Comment: My code attached above

Answer (score -1):

This issues because of google updates, once you change to gradle files it will execute fine as mentioned below

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
```

**Change the Gradle files to**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:**11.0.4**'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:**11.0.4**'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:**11.0.4**'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:**25.3.1**'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:**25.3.1**'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**25.3.1**'
```